# what are the functions of PPPoE server?

Tags: networking

I have searched in the internet about PPPoE server, the answers all about how to setup PPPoE server.  But I would like to know what actually PPPoE server is and what are the functionalities of PPPoE server?

Comment: This quesetion is more appropirate on http://serverfault.com/. Most probably you might use PPPoE to createa a VPN, however this currently might be not the best solution. Also, have you tried wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-point_protocol_over_Ethernet ?

Comment: A server is an application-layer concept, but PPPoE is a layer-2 concept. The idea of a PPPoE server is not realistic.